# Repeat gif file animation using MediaElement control in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, mediaelement

I want to play GIF (.gif) file repeatly in WPF applications by using  MediaElement controls.
Below i have attached my currently using code.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="recImageMedia"  Height="67" Margin="43,-70,816.2,0" LoadedBehavior="Play" Source="file://C:\Users\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Application\TempApplication\Snapshots\recordanim.gif" Visibility="Visible" />
```

Comment: There are a lot of suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975388/c-sharp-wpf-how-to-repeat-mediaelement-playback-from-mediaended-event-handler-wi

Comment: private void gifAnimation_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    gifAnimation.Position = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
    gifAnimation.Play();
 }

Comment: This is worked for me.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow suggests at least two possible solutions to your problem. The first is to use the MediaTimeline control as referenced here

[MediaTimeline SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510364/how-a-continuous-play-gif-file-in-wpf)

Alternatively, you may find some use in utilising MediaElement from WPF MediaKit

[WPF MediaKit SO Answer](https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit)